# fixing date shape in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[dataset in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHJvc.png)
Hello, I have been trying to standardize the date in the year column to get rid of the decimals and and the random format and keep only the years.

Is there an efficient way to do this in Pandas?

Comment: Have you looked into `pd.to_datetime`?  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: @IanThompson yes! I did try it but I keep getting this error : TypeError: invalid string coercion to datetime

Comment: @IanThompson I think it is because of a wrong formal in the data ... IllegalMonthError: bad month number 21; must be 1-12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Setup

```py
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1


so = pd.DataFrame({
    "Countries": [*["Canada"]*5, *["Brazil"]*5],
    "Year": [1990.0, 1991.0, 1992.0, 1993.0, 1994.0, 2020.0, 2021.0, 2021.0, "2011-21", 2021.0],
    "Value": 1  # placeholder
})

print(so)
```

```
  Countries     Year  Value
0    Canada   1990.0      1
1    Canada   1991.0      1
2    Canada   1992.0      1
3    Canada   1993.0      1
4    Canada   1994.0      1
5    Brazil   2020.0      1
6    Brazil   2021.0      1
7    Brazil   2021.0      1
8    Brazil  2011-21      1
9    Brazil   2021.0      1
```

## Explanation

Inspecting the `.dtype` of `so.Year` we get `object`

```py
print(so.Year.dtype)
```

```
object
```

I'm making an assumption that all years in `so.Year` will be 4-digit, so I convert to `str` and limit to the first four characters

```py
so["NewYear"] = so.Year.astype(str).str[:4]

print(so)
```

```
  Countries     Year  Value NewYear
0    Canada   1990.0      1    1990
1    Canada   1991.0      1    1991
2    Canada   1992.0      1    1992
3    Canada   1993.0      1    1993
4    Canada   1994.0      1    1994
5    Brazil   2020.0      1    2020
6    Brazil   2021.0      1    2021
7    Brazil   2021.0      1    2021
8    Brazil  2011-21      1    2011
9    Brazil   2021.0      1    2021
```

Now you can either use the `NewYear` column as-is, or convert to some other `dtype`.